# JSLint with Sublime text 2 - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sublimetext2, jslint, sublime-jslint

I have installed JSlint properly but when I tried to run it I got below error:

[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: [u'/usr/local/bin/node', u'/usr/local/bin/jslint', u'--sloppy', u'--indent', u'2', u'--node', u'--nomen', u'--vars', u'--plusplus', u'--stupid', u'']]
[dir: C:\Users\agrawal_d\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Python27;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\agrawal_d\AppData\Roaming\npm]
[Finished]

Not understanding why it's showing this, can anyone please give me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem as well and I hacked the file `JSLint.sublime-build` under installed JSLint package directory by replacing `/usr/local/bin/node` by the path to my node and it works.

Seems you're installing sublime text under windows platform. maybe you need to find the path to your node installation (e.g., `C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin\node`) and make sure the JSLint package can find it.

Comment: I am not using nodejs. How can i use JSHint?

Answer (score 0):

jslint most likely must be separately installed on your computer using Node and NPM package manager

Please follow the plug-in installation instructions on the plug-in README.

Here is a guide with some pictures

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/04/12/jslint-integration-for-sublime-text-2/

Comment: Also I recommend using SublimeLint + jshint instead of jslint

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird but in my case the solution is different. I was getting following error:
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'c:\\users\\arvind~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\SublimeLinter3-arvind\\app.js'`

I checked the `c:\\users\\arvind~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\` folder and found that it had not `SublimeLinter3-arvind` folder. I created this folder manually and JSHint it started working..